# Autofac error - No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, dependency-injection, autofac, autofactory

In one of my web applications, I have a web service that is using Autofac, the svc file is as follows:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
Service="MyApp.WebServices.Contracts.Interfaces.IMyWebService, MyApp.WebServices.Contracts" 
Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" %>
```

I register the dependencies for my web service application like this:

```
public class IocConfig
{        
    public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();            

        //web services
        builder.RegisterType<MyWebService>().As<IMyWebService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var container = builder.Build();

        AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;            
    }
}
```

From another web application, I want to connect to those services also using Autofac, so I register the dependencies like:

```
public class IocConfig
{
    //Ioc dependencies for frontend application
    public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

        builder
            .Register(c => new ChannelFactory<ISomeWebService>(
                new BasicHttpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/MyApp.WebServices/MyWebService.svc")))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        //register service proxies
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IMyWebService>>().CreateChannel())
            .As<IMyWebService>()
            .UseWcfSafeRelease();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

Inside one of the controllers, I do the following:

```
public SomeController(IMyWebService myServiceProxy) 
    {
        _myServiceProxy = myServiceProxy;

        var response =_myServiceProxy.CallSomeMethod(new Request()
        {
            EmailAddress = "test@test.com"
        });
    }
```

The myServiceProxy of type IMyWebService is being resolved, I see that it is a transparent proxy, but when I call the "CallSomeMethod" I get an error:

**No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.**

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Per the docs, WCF doesn't support per-request lifetime scope.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html) If your service implementation is taking dependencies, you can't register them as per request.

[There is an FAQ telling you how to troubleshoot this and alternatives you can use.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html)

Comment: Changed my dependencies lifetime from InstancePerRequest to InstancePerLifetimeScope and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Also, my NHibernate session factory is still a SingleInstance lifetime and it works, the problem is indeed with InstancePerRequest.